# Never backed up to iTunes or iCloud. Recovery mode

Tags: itunes, iphone

I never backed up my iPhone 6 to iTunes or iCloud and now my phone is broke and I can't pass the main screen or passcode screen. Touch is not working. I already have  a another iPhone 6, but is there a way 
to backup my broken phone? I went to recovery mode on my old iPhone 6 and I see two options 'Update' or 'Restore'. Which option will take backup of my phone?

Comment: Neither. backups are what you do *in case* of such a problem, not *after*.

Comment: I have most recent update pending on my iPhone, what happens if I use iTunes to update that? any advantage?

Comment: You'll still need to be able to unlock it to update, either code or touch ID. Update won't back it up, though you might get chance to back it up to iTunes if it stays awake afterwards. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You might  wanna try copytrans manager or iexplorer